# What is the R equivalent to Stata's fillin?

Tags: r, stata

Stata's [`fillin`](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dfillin.pdf) command makes a dataset rectangular. 
How can I do the same in **R**?

As a reproducible example, say that I have the data below:

```
data <- data.frame(season = c("2016-17","2017-18","2018-19", "2018-19"), group=c("A","A","A","B"), value=c(1,2,3,6))
```

I would like to get the following:

```
data_wanted <- data.frame(season = c("2016-17","2017-18","2018-19", "2018-19", "2016-17", "2017-18"), group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),value=c(1,2,3,6,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyr::complete`, just specify that you want every combination of season and group:

```
tidyr::complete(data, season, group)
```